# Android Sqlite query runs in 4.0 but not in 2.3

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

I have the following query that I run on the database in Android

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c;

String Query = "Select * from SubCategory_List where CatId = (Select _id from Category_List where Name = ?) order by Name ASC";

c = db.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { CatName });
```

I use this cursor to populate the listview. In android 4.0 i get the desired output, But in 2.3 the vales are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
String Query = "Select * from SubCategory_List where CatId = (Select _id from Category_List where Name = ?) order by Name ASC";
```

by this :

```
String Query = "Select * from SubCategory_List where CatId IN (Select _id from Category_List where Name = ?) order by Name ASC";
```

*(Changing = into IN)*

Comment: Why is "IN" required ? the inner query returns only a single value.